# Why extra conditions to prove that $g(x) = \Sigma f(mx)$ and $f(x) = \Sigma \mu(n)g(nx)$ are equivalent

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I'm trying to solve the following problem

> Suppose that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}d_3(k)|f(kx)| \lt \infty,$$
>   where $d_3(k)$ denotes the number of factorizations of $k$ as a product of three numbers. Show that if $$ g(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}f(mx),$$ then $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)g(nx)$$and conversly.

My probelm is that I seem to have proved it without using the condition about $d_3$. Here's how my proof goes:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)g(nx) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}f(mnx)=\sum_{m,n}\mu(n)f(mnx)={\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(nx)\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)}=f(x)$

the converse goes very similarly, so my question is where exactly is the mistake in this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $\tau(m) = \sum_{d | m} 1$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty|\mu(n) f(knx)|\le\sum_{m=1}^\infty  \tau(m) | f(mx)| \tag{1}$$
If  $(1)$ converges, $g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(kx)$ converges and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) g(nx)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(n) f(knx) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(mx) \sum_{d | m} \mu(d) = f(x)$$
since absolute convergence means the order of summation doesn't matter.

Comment: oh so there isn't really a mistake in the proof, it's just that we need to make sure $g(x)$ is well defined?

Comment: @H_Hassan we need to make sure everything is well defined : $\sum_{k=1}^\infty  f(kx) $ and changing the order of summation  in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(n) f(knx) $

Comment: how does $\tau$ relate to $d_3$ tho?

Comment: @H_Hassan note that the Riemann hypothesis  is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(k x)}{k^s}= \sin(x)$ (as a distribution) whenever $Re(s) > 1/2$

Comment: @H_Hassan $d_3$ is too strong here. $\tau = d_2$